# Plan Cache Limits and the Local Memory Pressure in Sql Server 2022

Tags: sql-server, plan-cache

I am doing research about Sql Server Plan Cache Limits and the Local Memory Pressure. I have found this article by [Erin Stellato](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/sql-server-plan-cache-limits/)  but it was written four years ago and I am not sure it is still valid in Sql Server 2022. A complete explanation of the topic, reporting basically the same criteria explained by Erin, exists in an [older official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc293624(v=technet.10)) about Sql Server 2005.
The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#execution-plan-caching-and-reuse) related to Sql Server 2022 does not give precise information about the limits of the Plan Cache and about “when” the Local Memory Pressure is triggered.
I am not going to report here the Plan Cache Limits reported in the above articles to keep the question as shorter as possible. They are clearly explained in Erin’s article.
Does anyone know if there is a reliable document, referring to Sql Server 2022, and related to this topic?